# Getting Countries and telephone codes

Tags: validation, localization, country-codes

I thing this is really common problem when developing an app. The problem is to get country list with telephone numbers. So I need to get for example:

```
+380 Ukraine
+1 USA
...
```

Diving deeper into this, as application will be localized for the App Store, I should get it with translations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JSON string and use it in your app (hardcode and parse). 
https://gist.github.com/Goles/3196253 or you can use a rest service like https://restcountries.eu/